# Atmel's SAM C21 not available?

Tags: atmel

I was looking for a nice MCU for my next project and stumbled over the Atmel SAM C21 (ATSAMC21E18A-AUT). Unfortunately it seems to be not available, although there is a C21 evaluation board on sale.
Is the product still in "beta" phase and therefore not available or is it canceled / retired?

Comment: (1) Post this question to Atmel. They can provide the definitive answer. Anyone else would be only guessing. (2) This question is about procurement, and it's not a good fit for EE.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C21, AFAIK, is a new chip, so it's likely they have not been distributed yet.

Setting up the distribution paths can be a complex thing, with offers and proposals and time to process on both sides for the whole range of packages and making a pricing scheme.

And it's usual for companies to push out their Dev Boards Revision 1 early, because that's usually what engineers like to play with to make up their mind about a chip, so if you delay that, you're losing potential customers.